# how to create a wrapper for an executable file

Tags: malware

What I want to do is to modify the behavior of a binary file ( but I don't have sourcecode of this file). One solution I can think about is to create a wrapper, and this wrapper can defer some API calls or add additional API calls. Do you know is there any existing libraries support this? 
Thank you.

Comment: hi, I searched, but all the suggestions I got are related to how to convert jar to exe or to create exe from python code, not a wrapper for exe. Could you please give me one option? Thank you.

Comment: sure, change your search term: "malware wrapper"

Answer (score 5):

Windows executables interacts with OS  (WinAPI) functions through system DLLs. Without modifying the exe, one trick is to hijack those calls - search for "dll injection".

Comment: Don't forget about LD_PRELOAD on Linux.

Comment: Agree that "dll injection" is one trick to hijack those calls. Indeed, my intent is to create a wrapper for malwares such that I can modify the behavior of them in a generic way.